# Why does the runnable thread does not work?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

[image]I am new to threading in android. I want to invoke a new runnable thread on `onCreate()` method. I mean when `onCreate()` method called, thread also called which I use to do animated work. 
I make a basic app for testing the thread but it does not works.
following my source code. kindly tell me the reason behind, and how to fix it. thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            t.start();
    }


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "thread called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify what the expected behavior ?

Comment: You need to explain " does not works.". Errors, does nothing, does something other than what you expect...

Comment: unable to start activity.

Comment: @codeMagic, a Toast in a Thread. What else might it be, orb

Comment: @Blackbelt orb hard telling if there's something before that's causing another issue. Also, trying to teach OP to fish because I'm out of tuna ;)

Comment: @codeMagic, orb fair enough

Comment: @Blackbelt so kind. Roshaan, "unable to start activity" isn't very specific

Comment: also `requestWindowFeature` can't be used after `setContentView`

Comment: Please post actual code/error messages instead of screen shots in the future. But the error says what @Blackbelt was saying. "requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

Answer (score 0):

Your thread works, but a Toast must be displayed on the main thread of the application.
Try using:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "thread called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

That's how you put things in the UI Thread when not in the UI thread.